# Sending data from an iPhone app to a Node.js web server

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, node.js, socket.io

I took [this code](https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-ios-client) for making a sinatra webserver and made my own Node.js version using express. Then I got [this code](https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-ios-client) to work on the iPhone for getting data from the server. The iphone app sends an HTTP request for '/sushi.json' and the server handles this with `app.get('/sushi.json', function(request, response))`. The server then sends a JSON string back to the iOS app which then parses it into an array so it can make use of it.

But what if I want to *send* data *to* the server? In the iPhone app how would I build and send the JSON string, and how would the server watch for it?

Also, I didn't need to use socket.io to get this to work. Is that something that should be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, socket.io is if you want to keep a persistent stream between your server and client. The main use for that is when you need your server to be able to push data to the client rather then the client requesting it.

To post some JSON you will use the same code as before but create the request object slightly differently:

```
__autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                            options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                                                       result, @"my_json", nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                            path:@"/myobject" parameters:params];
```

You will get your data on the server via

```
JSON.parse(request.params['my_json'])
```

Comment: There is no parameters: method in NSMutableURLRequest.

Comment: I'll update the answer later with a more complete explanation, but httpClient is an instance of a class in the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/afnetworking/afnetworking) library that you are using. See the link and check the docs, you might be able to figure it out. Googling 'afnetworking send data to server' should help as well.

Comment: @JakubHampl do you require any external libs for your code to run? (such as AFNetworking)? Thanks.

Comment: @JakubHampl Edit: I've added AFNetworking to my project but could you please explain what httpClient is and what class it is from? Thanks.